# spark worker cannot connect to master

Tags: java, apache-spark

My spark worker cannot connect to master. I've tried:

- adding `spark-env.sh` like some answers I found, set `SPARK_MASTER_HOST`=IP
- restarted both the master and worker

None of them worked.

Here's what I did:

```sh
start spark master
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /<MY-PATH>/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/logs/spark-<MY-USERNAME>-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-<SPARK_ID>.out
start spark worker: spark://<SPARK_ID>:7077
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /<MY-PATH>/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/logs/spark-<MY-USERNAME>-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-<SPARK_ID>.out
```

The spark master starts and I can get the master's URL. The worker also starts. However, it cannot connect to the master because:

```
21/08/06 15:33:07 INFO Worker: Connecting to master <SPARK_ID>:7077...
21/08/06 15:33:10 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master <SPARK_ID>:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to <SPARK_ID>/192.168.1.175:7077
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:287)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: <SPARK_ID>/192.168.1.175:7077
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:715)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/08/06 15:33:12 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 4)
21/08/06 15:33:12 INFO Worker: Connecting to master <SPARK_ID>:7077...
21/08/06 15:33:13 ERROR Worker: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if master is running by checking log files under $SPARK_HOME/logs.
You should see logs as shown below:

```
21/08/07 02:56:04 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
21/08/07 02:56:04 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://<your host>:7077
21/08/07 02:56:05 INFO Master: Running Spark version 3.1.2
21/08/07 02:56:05 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
21/08/07 02:56:05 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://<your IP>:8080
21/08/07 02:56:05 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
```

while starting worker pass master url which you get from above log.

Comment: I confirm that my spark master started. I got the same log like you wrote.
However, when I start my worker, the http://localhost:8080/ still shows 0 worker and the log shows the same error I described above.